# Loop through temporary table in trigger

Tags: mysql, loops, triggers

I have this trigger that cointains a temporary table. Now I wish to loop through the temporary table and do something on each row. Is there some easy way of doing this? I have googled but everything seems overly complicated for such a simple task.

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.col <> OLD.col THEN
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpTable;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpTable AS (my select statement);
    --For each row in tempTable--
        Do something
    --
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTable;
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Often one does not need an extra table. What is your query? Maybe it can be done in one step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to have rownumber You can do:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpTable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpTable AS (
SELECT  l.*,
    @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_no
FROM    XXX_TABLE l
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r);
```

to use it You can use `WHILE` loop:

```
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmpTable INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
  SET i = i + 1;

  -- do sth WHERE row_no=i;

END WHILE;
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to accept your answer earlier, Haven't got much time for SO recently =/ It was helpful, thanks!